# postgres: list role grants for all users

Tags: postgresql

I have an audit requirement to query all roles granted to users; listed by user.
For example:

```
Username   Roles
user1      role1_rw, role2_ro, rol3_rw
user2      role2_rw
```

I cannnot use psql meta-commands as this result set will be merged with some other queries to do analysis of the grants.
The roles have been created to manage ro/rw access to various application schemas.
In oracle, this is quite straight forward; I dont see a single view to return this in Postgres. The querying user is a superuser.

Does anyone have a query to return this?
Postgres 9.4 on ubuntu

Comment: The `psql` meta-commands are backed by ordinary SQL queries.  Just do a `\set ECHO_HIDDEN on` before running a `\du`, for example.  It will show you the query being used to obtain the output.

Answer (score 21):

You can see the users using the `psql` client with the option `\du+`(like @dezso already explained).

But, if you want it, you can make a query on `pg_roles`, eg:

```
  SELECT 
      r.rolname, 
      r.rolsuper, 
      r.rolinherit,
      r.rolcreaterole,
      r.rolcreatedb,
      r.rolcanlogin,
      r.rolconnlimit, r.rolvaliduntil,
  ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
        WHERE m.member = r.oid) as memberof
, r.rolreplication
, r.rolbypassrls
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
ORDER BY 1;
```

Please, take a look at the documentation for more details:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/user-manag.html

Comment: What version does this require?  (`r.rolbypassrls` does not exist in 9.2.7.)

Answer (score 7):

+1 for Sebastian's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/145786/2470).

I don't have the reputation to add a comment but I'd like to answer RonJohn's question as well.  `rolbypassrls` was introduced in postgresql version `9.5`.  You can see this by comparing the `pg_roles` doc page between versions [9.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/view-pg-roles.html) and [9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/view-pg-roles.html).  (You may also notice the other difference is `rolcatupdate` was removed)

Here is Sebastion's snippet simply adjusted for the missing column:

```
SELECT 
      r.rolname, 
      r.rolsuper, 
      r.rolinherit,
      r.rolcreaterole,
      r.rolcreatedb,
      r.rolcanlogin,
      r.rolconnlimit, r.rolvaliduntil,
  ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
        WHERE m.member = r.oid) as memberof
, r.rolreplication
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
ORDER BY 1;
```